# New composer package that uses Guzzle - cant find it

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm learning how to make a composer package. So far I've done this:

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "Iv/MyPackage",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Iv\\MyPackage\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Iv\\MyPackage\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a class under the namespace: `namespace Iv\MyPackage\Api;` called `Consumer` and in its `__construct` method it has this:

```
public function __construct(array $credentials)
{
    $this->client = new Client();
    $this->credentials = $credentials;
}
```

And on the top of that class I have `use GuzzleHttp\Client;`.

The error I'm getting is:
`Fatal error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in path\to\package\Iv\MyPackage\src\Api\Consumer.php on line 27` when I do:

```
$package = new Iv\MyPackage\Api\Consumer(['user', 'password']);
$query = $api->prepare('/api-endpoint', 'GET');
```

**Edit**:

This is what my `Consumer` class looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Iv\MyPackage\Api;


use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class Consumer
{
    private $credentials = [];

    public function __construct(array $credentials)
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
    }
    ...
}
```

Also I'm using PhpStorm, which tells me that I have the `GuzzleHttp` package, because it autoimports it for me when I type `Client()` and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Which means I have ran `composer install/update`.

**Edit 2**:
I have a file - `index.php` which has the following:

```
<?php
include('vendor/autoload.php');

$api = new Iv\MyPackage\Api\Consumer(['user', 'password']);

$query = $api->prepare('/endpoint', 'GET');

var_dump($api->execute($query));
```

The folder structure is as it follows:

```
-Iv/
--MyPackage/
---src/
----Api/
----Exceptions/
----vendor/
----tests/
----otherfiles (composer.json, phpunit.xml, etc)
-vendor/
-composer.json
-index.php (I mentioned above)
```

**Edit 3**:
The content of my `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`:

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/yaml'),
    'Psr\\Http\\Message\\' => array($vendorDir . '/psr/http-message/src'),
    'Iv\\MyPackage\\Tests\\' => array($baseDir . '/tests'),
    'Iv\\MyPackage\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/psr7/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/promises/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src'),
    'Doctrine\\Instantiator\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/instantiator/src/Doctrine/Instantiator'),
);
```

**Edit 4**:

In the folder where is `index.php` I have this composer:

```
{
  "name": "Test MyPackage",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Iv\\MyPackage\\": "Iv/MyPackage/src"}
  }
}
```

^^ I saw that on SO in a topic that OP was asking how to test his package before uploading it to packagist/git. I can load the `Consumer` class, no errors about it, but every dependency is not found. (`GuzzleHttp\Client`, `Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser`, etc)

Comment: It is confusing to follow your `namespace` and `use` statements out of context of the code. Could you edit the fragment of your `Consumer::__construct()`  to show the `namespace, use` where they are placed?

Comment: stupid question: did you run `composer install` to install dependencies?

Comment: You don't specify so I must ask - did you remember to `composer install` after creating your `composer.json`?  Do you have a `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` to activate the composer autoloader? Those would be possible explanations for it not being found. The guzzle requirement in `require-dev` is not needed, by the way.

Comment: another stupid question: do you have a `require vendor/autoload.php';` in your code?

Comment: I answered to all of you in the edits. Thanks.

Comment: could you please check if `GuzzleHttp\\Client` is present in your `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` file?

Comment: @marcosh, yes it is. I posted the content of that file in the question. Or atleast `\\GuzzleHttp` is.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I tried to replicate what you posted on your question. To me it fails but with another error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Iv\MyPackage\Api\Consumer' not found in /home/marcosh/projects/test/index.php on line 4`. If I edit `composer.json` with `"Iv\\MyPackage\\": "Iv/MyPackage/src/"` everything works as expected

Comment: I really can't see anything wrong with the way the autoloader is setup. Are you able to instantiate a different class, like `new \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser()` ?

Comment: @marcosh I have no idea. I'm so new to this :(

Comment: @Michael, I tried creating a new isntance of the Parser, it failed again with the same error :(

Comment: @marcosh can you see the 4th edit of this question. The composer.json I have.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova ok I guess that you're missing the reference to your package in the main `composer.json`

Comment: @marcosh which one do you refer as the `main`?

Comment: the one in the same directory as the `index.php`

Comment: @marcosh I have this `"psr-4": {"Iv\\MyPackage\\": "Iv/MyPackage/src"}` isn't it enough? What should I put there?

Comment: that line will just autoload your classes, but will not tell composer to autoload Guzzle or the other libraries. To do this you have to tell composer to look also in the other `composer.json` file, the one inside your package. I'm writing an answer on how to do it

Comment: @marcosh I'm such a noob here. Can you tell me how to tell composer to look also in the other `composer.json` or give me a hint what should I search in google?

Answer (score 1):

In the `composer.json` in the main directory you are missing a reference to your package. You are just autoloading it, but you are not autoloading all of its dependencies.

To do this you have to add a section like this in your `composer.json` in the main directory:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "url": "path/to/your/package",
        "type": "path"
    }
]
```

and add it to the `require` section, some thing like:

```
"require": {
    "Iv/MyPackage" : "dev-master"
}
```

Alternatively, you could just move your dependencies from the `composer.json` inside your package to the one in the main directory

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said and that created a `vendor` folder in my main directory. I still get the error that the Yaml `Parser` is not found. Even though I removed it from my code. Ran `composer update` in both dirs. First in the package's dir and then in the main. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much mixed everything up a bit, but it is solvable.

What I see is that you have an odd directory structure: You have `Iv/MyPackage/src/...` in your main project (i.e. on the same level there is a file `composer.json`).

IF you want to use your "Iv/MyPackage" as a Composer package in your main project, you have to add it as a dependency. This means that your package name must appear inside a `"require"`-Section in the main `composer.json` file. Currently it is not. Instead of this, you manually added autoloading for the path your package is currently in - without telling Composer that this should be treated as a package, and that it has dependencies that should also be downloaded.

You added the dependencies of your package inside the directory of it, but this is not how Composer works.

To fix it, you have to do two simple things:

1. Add your package as a dependency in your main `composer.json`.
2. If your package is currently hosted in a private repository, you have to add it's URL to the `repositories` key in `composer.json`.

The first one is just this:

```
{
  "name": "Test MyPackage",
  "require": {
    "Iv/MyPackage": "dev-master"
  },
  "autoload": {
  }
}
```

Remove the autoloading for your package - it is contained inside that package already. If you want Composer to autoload your main project, add that autoloading here (and I suggest you do, because you'd probably cannot write a better autoloader yourself).

Second thing is adding the repository:

```
{
  "name": "Test MyPackage",
  "repositories": [
    { 
      "type": "vcs", 
      "url": "your repo url, either http or ssh" 
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "Iv/MyPackage": "dev-master"
  },
  "autoload": {
  }
}
```

This tells Composer to look into that repository and see if it can find something. Everything found is added to the collection of known packages (with the default source being Packagist) and used to select the best version matches.

Some corrections you should apply:

1. Package names should be lower case, so it's better to use `iv/mypackage`.
2. If you give a name in your main project, it has to follow the form `<vendor>/<package>`, not be some random string with a name. Composer will not deny working, but once you get there you will benefit from more of the available infrastructure in the Composer area, and correct names will help you. Otherwise, just leave it out for the moment.

This should set you up and running. I probably can answer more details you didn't even ask, but suggest you read about Composer on the documentation page or here on Stackoverflow, because the common problems usually have already been solved.